# Disabling SMTP verbs on Windows 2008 & IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, smtp

I am running the SMTP service from IIS 7 and would like to disable the SMTP "turn" verb.  The SMTP service is configured through the IIS 6.0 Manager (if this helps)

Google has not been too much help in finding a solution to this problem.  I have search on both IIS 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://onhacks.org/lang/en/2009/01/03/enabledisable-esmtp-advertisement/). It's for IIS 6, but it may be similar in IIS 7.

It shows how to disable different verbs for the IIS SMTP server by editing the metabase.

**UPDATE**

I just did some more digging, and IIS 7 (I haven't actually used it yet) has replaced the metabase with config files located in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`, so that should be a good place to start.